# R remove character from date value

Tags: r, string, date

I have a `data.frame`, with a typical date column goes like this: `29-Jan-14`,...

However, some of the date values begin with a character `T`, they look like this: `T29-Jan-14`,...

How do I delete that `T`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sub` on the vector of "dates".

```
> sub("^T", "", "T29-Jan-14")
[1] "29-Jan-14"
```

Comment: Thanks! But this applies to some other dates too, I can't replace them with this one date, I have to delete all values begin with this "T" character. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just try my solution with a vector of dates (for example, your column in your `data.frame`) and see what happens?